# Error: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file

Tags: node.js

we have an node js application , running on node version 8 , we want to migrate it to version 10 , i have  reinstalled,node js 10 , after that i am running my node server.js , but its showing below  Error. i found that its related to firebase module , i have upgraded  fire base module also , but its displaying same error. how to upgarde to node 10 and its dependent  module?

```
Error: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
at Sign.sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:83:26)
at Object.sign (C:\new-rest-api\node_modules\jwa\index.js:55:49)
at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (C:\new-rest-api\node_modules\jws\lib\sign-stream.js:23:24)
at Object.module.exports [as sign] (C:\new-rest-api\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:186:16)
at CertCredential.createAuthJwt_ (C:\new-rest-api\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\credential.js:229:20)
at CertCredential.getAccessToken (C:\new-rest-api\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\credential.js:199:26)
at FirebaseAppInternals.getToken (C:\new-rest-api\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-app.js:68:73)
at AuthTokenProvider.getToken (C:\new-rest-api\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\cjs\src\core\AuthTokenProvider.js:34:49)
at PersistentConnection.establishConnection_ (C:\new-rest-api\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\cjs\src\core\PersistentConnection.js:597:18)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\new-rest-api\node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\cjs\src\core\PersistentConnection.js:497:19)
at ontimeout (timers.js:425:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5)
at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5)
at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue today.
My problem was that my OPENSSL_CONF environment variable was not set up correctly. Make sure openssl is installed and OPENSSL_CONF is pointing to openssl.cfg