# Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Server is in Linux but we tried to publish .net core folder. It's working fine in IIS but not working in Linux server.
We are following below manner of project deployment to google server.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/4-ways-you-can-deploy-an-aspnet-core-app-to-gcp

Tried since 4 days.
I need to convert my certificate read code into linux sever mode is below.

```
string base64str = Convert.ToBase64String(Certificate);
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(baseBytes, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

We are used above line for generating signed url of which file are stored at google repositories.

Comment: Can you please describe the problem in these terms? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your code is fine (for the part that you have show). What problem do you have, what error is happening, etc. Read you own question and then try to guess what you are trying to ask and what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Exactly issue in reading file of certificate.

Comment: I am also finding solution. Issue is similar in nodejs.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736310/error-error2006d080bio-routinesbio-new-fileno-such-file

Comment: Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824859/how-to-run-dockered-asp-net-core-app-generated-by-visual-studio-2019-on-linux-p

Comment: Did @BRBdot answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when running docker locally and what fixed it is by specifying the cert and password.

`docker run -i -p 443:443 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path="name_of_file.pfx" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="password_here"`

Note that you need to specify the correct case in the filename and also use double quotes and not single quotes. No quotes also work but if the text needs escaping then it will be trouble so better use double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had wrong path for this environment variable.

```
ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: 'path/localhost.pfx'
```

So I corrected the path to required pfx file and it worked like a charm.